# I have a MySQL 5.6.17 server on OSX 10.9.2 that "sometimes starts", and most of the time don't

Tags: mysql, macos

I have setup a MySQL 5.6.17 server on my Mac OSX 10.9 to run some demo (I usually do not attempt MySQL and Apache things on a Mac), using Homebrew.

Everything went just fine (apart usual stinky parts about the mysql.sock file not being in the right place)

BUT: When I start my machine, it is supposed to be up and running. However, most (if not all) of the time, it isn't. When I go for `sudo /usr/local/bin/mysql.server start`, I get that:

```
iMac-de-Mathieu:~ mathieubolla$ sudo /usr/local/bin/mysql.server start
Password:
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/iMac-de-Mathieu.local.pid).
```

I can do it repeatedly, nothing happens.

But I discovered something even more interesting: If I `cd /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.17/bin` and I repeatedly delete the error file and attempt `sudo mysql.server start`, it will eventually work.

Here is a log I obtained while writing this message:

```
iMac-de-Mathieu:bin mathieubolla$ sudo mysql.server
Usage: mysql.server  {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status}  [ MySQL server options ]
iMac-de-Mathieu:bin mathieubolla$ sudo mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/iMac-de-Mathieu.local.pid).
iMac-de-Mathieu:bin mathieubolla$ sudo rm /usr/local/var/mysql/iMac-de-Mathieu.local.err
iMac-de-Mathieu:bin mathieubolla$ sudo mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/iMac-de-Mathieu.local.pid).
iMac-de-Mathieu:bin mathieubolla$ sudo rm /usr/local/var/mysql/iMac-de-Mathieu.local.err
iMac-de-Mathieu:bin mathieubolla$ sudo mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/iMac-de-Mathieu.local.pid).
iMac-de-Mathieu:bin mathieubolla$ sudo rm /usr/local/var/mysql/iMac-de-Mathieu.local.err
iMac-de-Mathieu:bin mathieubolla$ sudo mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
. SUCCESS!
```

I sure am a newbie at MySQL administration, even more on Mac OSX. But I'm also a veteran programmer, and I barely get any good reason why a software like MySQL may exhibit unpredictable behavior at startup. I understand some things can get non deterministic when running multithreaded soft sometimes, but starting up a data server, I do not know...

Any ideas what may be going on?

Here is error log:

```
140507 10:20:50 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2014-05-07 10:20:51 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation     for more details).
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.17/bin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [ERROR] InnoDB: ./ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Binlog end
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-05-07 10:20:51 11262 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.17/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140507 10:20:51 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/iMac-de-Mathieu.local.pid ended
```

Comment: "InnoDB: ./ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode" does that file exist? is it writeable for the MySQL database? Are you sure no other process is accessing this file?

Comment: I think so. I get `-rw-rw----  1 mathieubolla  admin    76M  7 mai 10:20 ibdata1` when I `ls /usr/local/var/mysql/`. Moreover, I do not change permissions when I run multiple startup attempts. I'll check the "other process" problem... Just have to remember how...

Comment: `lsof | grep ibdata1` returns nothing. I suppose this is proof nothing opens this file in my back, but not sure...

Comment: I think I see what seems to be the problem.. Under what user/group is your MySQL started? For me it looks like your data directory got messed up permissions..

Comment: But how could it start sometimes? I'm sure you're right, there is something bad with my permissions, but how could that vary with time? It might be an auxiliary problem that I have to fixe someday...

Comment: I also had this problem on Mac OS X 10.9.4 running MySQL 5.6. I guess the problem is on the MySQL installer script. So you'd rather start using `sudo bin/mysqld_safe` instead of using `mysql.server start` otherwise you will have permission denied error like I did.

Comment: Mysql works fine yesterday, and I didn't changed anything related mysql (include config and folder), but I got this same issue when I restarted my Mac today.

After I delete /usr/local/var/mysql/localhost.err, mysql starts normally.

PS: I tried "sudo mysql.server start" before I delete localhost.err, the error log actually got updated.